# javascript Cumulative arrows control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a rating system. What I have so far is three hearts that get colored when clicked, in a cumulative way (if the second one out of the three is clicked, the first and the two hearts are colored. if the third one is clicked, all the three are clicked). I'm not sure if it's clear but you can see an illustration of my code [here](http://jsbin.com/qukaduresu/edit?html,css,js,output)

What I got so far is :

HTML

```
<section id="like" class="rating">

  <!-- THIRD HEART -->
  <input type="radio" id="heart_3" name="like" value="3" />
  <label for="heart_3" class="heart-slider">&#9829;</label>
  <!-- SECOND HEART -->
  <input type="radio" id="heart_2" name="like" value="2" />
  <label for="heart_2" class="heart-slider">&#9829;</label>
  <!-- FIRST HEART -->
  <input type="radio" id="heart_1" name="like" value="1" />
  <label for="heart_1" class="heart-slider">&#9829;</label>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.rating {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;


  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
  display: none;
}

/* - - - - - LIKE */
#like {
  bottom: -65px;
}
#like:not(:checked) > label {
  cursor:pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 7.5px;

  color: rgba(233, 54, 40, .4);
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}
#like:not(:checked) > label:hover,
#like:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: rgba(233, 54, 40, .6);
}
#like > input:checked + label:hover,
#like > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
#like > input:checked ~ label:hover,
#like > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
#like > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
 color: rgb(233, 54, 40);

}
#like > input:checked ~ label {
  color: rgb(233, 54, 40);
}
```

JS

```
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {

      if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        heart_1.click();
    }
};
```

What I want to achieve now is :

1) to have the first heart already colored upon loading the page

2) keyboard controls with UP and DOWN arrows :

- first UP arrow gets the first+second heart colored
- second UP arrow gets the first+second+third heart colored

then,

- first DOWN arrow gets the third heart uncolored
- second DOWN arrow gets the third+second heart uncolored

I'm not quite familiar with Javascript and I would love to get some help on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first one coloured by simply adding checked="checked" as an attribute, and then carrying on from what you've already done, you could do something like:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        if (heart_2.checked) {
            heart_3.click();
        } else if (heart_1.checked) {
            heart_2.click();
        }
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        if (heart_3.checked) {
            heart_2.click();
        } else if (heart_2.checked) {
            heart_1.click();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks, JS works great.
For the already "checked" 1st heart upon page loading, what do you mean exactly by "adding as an attribute" ?

Comment: Change `<input type="radio" id="heart_1" name="like" value="1" />` to `<input type="radio" id="heart_1" name="like" value="1" checked="checked" />` and that'll make the first one selected initially

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.